# Replace only part of the complete string

Tags: regex, replace, pattern-matching

I am using regex to search for a pattern in my file(html, doesn't matter). The regex I'm using is:

```
.?.([0-9])
```

This captures the string of the form:

```
> 47.
```

However, I don't want to replace the whole of the string. I want to replace only "> " part leaving out the number. How do I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: Use lookahead instead?

Comment: What file editor are you using?

Comment: [`>\s*(?=\d+\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/KvSMbq/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
>\s*(\d+\.)(?!\d+)
```

Replace each match with contents of Group 1

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KvSMbq/4)**

**Explanation:**

- `>\s*` - matches `>` followed by 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+\.)` - matches 1+ digits followed by a `.`. This is captured in Group 1.
- `(?!\d+)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current match is not immediately followed by 1+ digits.

Replace each match with contents of Group 1.

Alternative solution: [`>\s*(?=\d+\.(?!\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/KvSMbq/3)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want it to work for decimal numbers. It's empty after "47. "

Comment: The you can just use [`>\s*(?=\d+\.(?!\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/KvSMbq/2) or [`>\s*(\d+\.)(?!\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KvSMbq/4)

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited the answer with the correct exp. that I was looking for.